# Distributed processing of CPU intensive COMs

Tags: com, distributed, mapreduce, qizmt

I have a 32 bit COM object that does CPU intensive processing (for now limited to a single CPU). In order to scale it up for very large datasets and user communities, I am thinking of employing distributed processing via MapReduce-like frameworks, like QizMt.

My question is, will QizMt work with COMs? 
Are there any other alternatives?

The logic inside the COM is rather complex, I would want to make the distributed processing as transparent to the original code as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the COM object designed to be run in a multi-threaded environment? IF not, then don't make it run that way.

This would mean you need a solution that runs one instance of the object in a each process.

Comment: Yes, it already runs in a multi-threaded environment, in a WCF application. Believe it or not, it was your advice, which I took and it worked out pretty well :-) .

Comment: So what would be the recommendation regarding distributed processing? Does QizMt work with COMs or my question doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Vadim: I know nothing about QizMt - I avoid COM objects wherever possible.